# Power BI How to show repeated values in the x-axis?

Tags: powerbi, visualization

Hi I am working on a report with date from Aug 2019 to Aug 2020. We want to keep the x-axis title short. It means August = A, September = S, October = O, so on and so forth.

I added the "Month" column with my own abbreviation style and added an "Index" column.

I used a "Line and Stacked column chart". The shared axis is "Month" and sort by column is "Index".
Since I have two A (because August in 2019 and 2020), Power BI still grouped them together.

How can I display them separately to look like this?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWWq5.png

Comment: What it is doing with A for April? I think you can all add Year to shared axis that means First Year then Month. This should not group them any more. But still confused about April and August for 2020.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking PowerBI to do two different things:

1. Aggregate date by your month abbreviation
2. Not to aggregate A (April) and A (August)

PowerBI does not allow you to cross the grain of your data like this. The only options I can think of to keep it succinct are to:

1. Use "Ap" and "Au"
2. Use "A" for April and "A " for August. The additional space should barely be noticeable in most visuals.